# fade HTML5 video image / poster in and out

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, fadein, fadeout

Is it possible to fade out the HTML5 video poster / oimage if we start the video and fade it in again when we pause or stop the video?

Normally the poster image is directly hidden when the video is started and also directly shown when we load the video / stop it

Maybe we can clone the poster image to a canvas, position it over the video and fade it out and in?

Is there an existing solution / script?

Comment: Could you simply alter the opacity of the div containing the poster?

Comment: the poster is part of the html5 video normally, currently it has not its own iv or something else as it is a normal parameter of html5 video (poster="imageurl")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the `poster` attribute is really driven by the `<video>` tag itself.  You're just telling it, before starting display this image.  Like any video element customization, this would require you to have your own elements involved.  Basically, you would have:

```
<div class="video-container" style="position:relative">
    <video width="x" height="y"></video>
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0">
</div>
```

You would then have to bind your events, for example with Zepto:

```
$('.video-container img').bind('click', function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        $vid = $img.parent().find('video');
    $img.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
        $img.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
        $vid[0].play();
    });
});
```

Similarly, you would listen for the pause event and when it occurs fade back in.

*That said*, this is probably a bad idea for two reasons:

1. This probably won't work for iOS or any device that prevents scripted playback.  In these devices, you can only trigger `play()` when inside a click event handler.  Since you're playing a second later, you don't really have control.
2. You're breaking default functionality.  When I pause a video, I may want to seek to another moment but I definitely want to know where I left off.  The lack of a visual queue takes that away.

**Update**

Here's a different approach that would help you get around the iOS difficulties.  In this case, you actually start the video on click, meaning there will be a period of time where the fading image covers the playing video, so it's your call.

```
$('.video-container').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this).find('img'),
        $vid = $(this).find('vid');

    $img.bind('click', function() { $vid[0].play() });

    $vid.bind('play', function() {
        $img.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
            if($vid[0].playing) {
                $img.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
            }
        });
    });

    $vid.bind('pause ended', function() {
        $img.css({visibility: 'visible'});
        $img.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, 'linear');
    });

});
```

Comment: dont need seeking but this looks very promising =)  seems zepto is quite the same as (old) jquery code

Comment: They're (mostly) API compatible.  I figured if you're using Video you're probably fine to use Zepto instead.  Unless, of course, you want IE9 support.