# Fading out the HTML5 video poster image oncanplaythrough

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to animate the poster attribute of the HTML5 video element. Anyone have any idea how I can target the poster attr using jQuery? What I want to to is have the poster img fade out as the video starts playing to avoid the jumpiness that is currently present. Here's the code...

HTML:

```
<video id="vid preload="auto" loop="loop" poster="images/firstFrame.png">
  <source src="video/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="video/bg.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");

  vid.oncanplaythrough = function() { 
    $('POSTER???').animate({'opacity': '0'});
    vid.oncanplay = vid.play();
  }
});
```

I've searched Google and SO without finding a solution for this problem. (I found this: [fade HTML5 video image / poster in and out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058635/fade-html5-video-image-poster-in-and-out) but it does not solve the problem)

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute selector in jquery.but we can't fadeout the poster beacuse it is part of video if you fadeout means full video be hide. So we are able to just remove the poster from the video.

```
    vid.oncanplaythrough = function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('poster' , '').fadeOut('fast');
        $this.fadeIn('fast');
      vid.oncanplay = vid.play();
  }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U2mQH/4/)

Comment: This fades the entire video out. Can you think of a solution that only fades the poster image out as the video plays in the background?

Comment: No dice I'm afraid. That only removes the link to the poster image. Anything that I put inside of the quotes is appended to the poster attribute, but I could find a way to animate the poster image itself. Even when selecting like so: `$('video[poster]')` the code is attached to the video element itself, which is why the code from before was effecting the entire video, and not just the placeholder image.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't know ask anybody

Comment: this link may be help for you

Comment: I was able to tweak your code to do exactly what I wanted to do. I will update my question with my solution to solve my specific issue. Thank you greatly @jqueryKing for your help, I would still be banging my head on the keyboard without it!

Comment: @JayWilsonJr. Can you please share your solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I faded out the poster, or more precisely faded IN the video.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <video id='video' controls="controls" muted="muted" autoplay="true" preload='none'>
    <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    <source id='webm' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm'/>
    <source id='ogv' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg'/>
    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* replaces the "cover" image in html5 video */
#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aqz-KE-bpKQ/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: black;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;                /* start faded out */ 
  transition: opacity 2s;    /* css fade in */
}
```

jQuery:

```
/* wait for all elements of DOM to be rendered */
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* force some of these attr */
    $("#video").attr({"autoplay": true,
                            "muted": true});

    /* double ensure that video is muted otherwise chrome
          won't autostart */
    $("#video").prop('muted', true);

    /* when video auto plays, it fades in */
    $("#video").bind('play', function (e) {
      $("#video").css('opacity', 1.0);
    });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wmodes/pen/bmOjLe)

[In action on my site](http://peoplesriverhistory.us/)

This works beautifully on chrome, but mileage may vary on other browsers.

Comment: Is there any way to start the video when fading out completed? I mean when poster is fading out the video already starts running.